# Showing DIV in collapse on small screen but normal on desktop

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to show Table DIV in COLLAPSE when someone opens page on MOBILE but on DESKTOP it should appear simple Table WITHOUT collapse.

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" 
  href="#table-collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" >
  Hello World
</a>

<table class="table table-borderless" id="table-collapse">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Country</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Country</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use `@media` queries, go check out MDN.

Comment: Not able to find solution for that :(

Answer (score 1):

You should use `media queries` for that. Here you can find some examples of how it works : https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

```css
    @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
     .small-screen { 
      color: green;
      }
      .big-screen { 
      display: none;
      }
    } 

    @media only screen and (min-width: 800px) {
     .small-screen { 
      display: none;
      }
     .big-screen { 
      color: blue;
      }
    }
```

```html
    <table class="small-screen table table-borderless">
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Country</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Country</td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
        <table class="big-screen table table-borderless">
         <tbody>
             <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Country</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td>City</td>
                <td>Country</td>
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

If u run this code on big screen the table content will be blue but when you resize the window to small size color will change. I hope this will explain to you how media queries work and how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by [Bootstrap Display](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/) properties.

I have tried something like you wanted using jQuery and Bootstrap version 4.

Here is the snippet. Try this may be this will help you.

```js
$("#showTable").click(function(){
    $("#collapsedTable").toggleClass('d-none d-sm-block');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="d-block d-sm-none" id="showTable">
  Hello World
</button>

<table class="table table-borderless d-none d-sm-block" id="collapsedTable">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Country</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>City</td>
            <td>Country</td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> Note: **To check the snippet, Open snippet on Fullpage and adjust the screen.** and Button will be displayed when you adjust the screen to small mobile size and table will be hidden at that time. When you click a button, table will be toggled.

Comment: @ikt Have you checked this?